# Is there any alternative for pause function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I want to pause a timer function (for like 5 seconds) in the middle of its execution in MATLAB GUI. `Pause(5)` can do it but the problem is that it pauses all other callback functions to execute (including other timer functions  I am using in the MATLAB GUI, for example).
I was thinkink maybe I can write a dummy loop that could be executed for 5 sec but it might not be accurate and efficient. Do you have any suggestion?

Additional info:

```
handles.maintmr = timer(...
 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
 'TasksToExecute',1,'StartDelay',299, 'Period', 1,...
 'TimerFcn', {@ttl_timer, hObject});

 handles.et_tmr = timer(...
 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
 'Period', 0.5, ...
 'TimerFcn', {@timer_ET_rec, hObject});

 handles.tmr = timer(...
 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
 'Period', 9.85, ...
 'TimerFcn', {@timer_update_display, hObject});
```

These are the defined three timer functions I am using in MATLAB GUI

And these are how I call the callback timer functions:

```
function timer_ET_rec(obj,event,hObject,eventdata)
 handles = guidata(hObject);

function timer_update_display(obj,event,hObject,eventdata)
handles = guidata(hObject); 

function ttl_timer(obj,event,hObject,eventdata) 
handles= guidata(hObject);
```

Comment: Can you show the timer function? this seems like a thing you would solve by modifying the timer function instead of suing pause.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  It sounds like you want some of your matlab code to pause whilst other parts should keep running? 

If you want to add a pause and keep the timer correct accounting for that pause there are few ways to go about that.

Comment: `handles.maintmr = timer(...
    'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
    'TasksToExecute',1,'StartDelay', exec_time, 'Period', 1,...
    'TimerFcn', {@ttl_timer, hObject});

handles.et_tmr = timer(...
    'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
    'Period', 0.5, ...
    'TimerFcn', {@timer_ET_rec, hObject});
    
handles.tmr = timer(...
        'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
        'Period', 9.85, ...
        'TimerFcn', {@timer_update_display, hObject});` These are the defined three timer functions I am using in MATLAB GUI

Comment: And these are how I call the callback timer functions:
`function timer_ET_rec(obj,event,hObject,eventdata)
handles = guidata(hObject);`
`function timer_update_display(obj,event,hObject,eventdata)
handles = guidata(hObject);`
`function ttl_timer(obj,event,hObject,eventdata)
handles= guidata(hObject);`

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the timer functions?!

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49674644/edit) your post to include the additional information.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure what you are aiming for.  Can you give us a more general idea of what code/process you are interrupting and what you are not? And why you are doing that?

Answer (score 4):

I would try something like

```
t = tic();
while toc(t) < 5
    pause(0.1);
    drawnow('limitrate');
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Edric, Thank you for the suggestion. It is clever to use tic toc structure and I tried it without 'pause' and 'drawnow' in the loop. But still it interrupts the other timer functions.

Answer (score 0):

I like Edric's solution.   Other options:

**Option 1**

The `waitfor(obj)` function (interrupts execution until object 'obj' is deleted).
eg.

```
    %Pop-up msg;
    h1 = errordlg({'This message interrupts the code.  Close me to continue'},...
        'Hi! I'm a pop-up')

    % interrupt until closed
    waitfor(h1)
```

**Option 2**

The `timer()` function doesn't run off the wallclock (ie. actual real world time) so I'm not sure it can do what you seem to what --- maintaining regular execution of code every `x` minutes regardless of interrupts and pauses in the code.  But some methods can get close to it.

a) use the timer function to regularly TEST if you have passed a particular period according to wallclock time or not (if statement with `clock()`). If so, execute some other code.

b) Change the timer `'BusyMode'` from the assumed default `'drop'` to `'queue'`and it will insert code to run as close as possible to the desired time.

---

Best solution will depend on what exactly you are trying to achieve.